# Can I open emacs in nw mode with the scratch buffer?

Tags: start-up, scratch-buffer

When starting emacs from the shell command line, if you pass the "dot", it opened emacs with a 'dired' of the current directory.

But can I do this?

```
emacs '*scratch*'
```

so emacs opens with the focus on the scratch buffer.

```
# my .bashrc
function emacs() {
  emacsclient -a "" -s workspace -nw "$@"
}
```

Comment: Your edit shows that you are conflating two different things.  Your question asks about running `emacs`, but your bash function shows that you are running `emacsclient`.  As you had already procured an answer to the original stated question, I suggest that you ask a new question if you want an answer about `emacsclient`.

Comment: okay thanks, !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to provide the "." in your command.  However, by default, there is a startup message shown.

```
emacs -nw --eval '(setq inhibit-startup-message t)'
```

or

```
emacs -nw --no-splash
```

should do what you want.

Comment: And, although I didn't mention it, setting the variable in your .emacs or .emacs.d/init.el file will make the behaviour persistent.