# Can I open emacs in nw mode with the scratch buffer? (when emacs is aliased to emacsclient session)

Tags: scratch-buffer

closed [that](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/53971/can-i-open-emacs-in-nw-mode-with-the-scratch-buffer?noredirect=1#comment84267_53971), re-incarnated here:

When starting emacs from the shell command line, if you pass the "dot", it opened emacs with a 'dired' of the current directory.

But can I do this?

```
emacs '*scratch*'
```

Basically I want to tell emacs (emacsclient) to be invoked with the argument "the file to be opened" being `*scratch*`

It would solve one of the problems I sometimes have:
fyi I always start my day with `cd ~/projecta; emacs .`
The issue with this is I can't freely kill 'dired' buffers.
If I `C-x k` the 'dired' buffer for `projecta` root, emacs frame closes
and I get dropped in to the shell.

Some context:

- using macOS
- Uses emacs *only* with Terminal.app ( -nw mode)
- Emacs is client/server based, and each of my "customers" get their own
  entry in my .bashrc

```
    function emacs() {
      emacsclient -a "" -s workspace -nw "$@"
    }

    function emacsb() {
      emacsclient -a "" -s workspaceb -nw "$@"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is `emacs -e '(switch-to-buffer "*scratch*")'`

Answer (score 0):

The first line of the output of `emacsclient --help` is

```
Usage: emacsclient [OPTIONS] FILE...
```

It suggests that a file or directory must be provided to the command.

Also, like you, I create per-directory emacs daemons:

```
ec() {
    SERVER_NAME=$(basename $PWD)
    emacsclient -a '' -s $SERVER_NAME $*
}
```

The advantage of this is that if I close the file or directory that the emacsclient is opened with, the daemon persists.